# Facebook Graph API - Attending list length != attending_count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Graph API - Event: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/

When I get the attending_count of an event the API returns the correct number of people attending an event.

When I request the list of people going via attending (Edge) I'm getting less people.

The problem is that the attending (Edge) request does not only return names, but also the user id of each user. The ones who have their ID set to Friends-only in their privacy settings are not being listed. 
I don't even need the ID, only the names. In my browser I can easily read ALL names, even of the people who set their ID to privat.

So is there away to get the names without the ID?
Tried to set the parameter fields to first_name only, so no ID, but still, it's giving me first_name AND ID of each attending user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people may have disabled the Facebook Platform, so they don´t show up in the list - but they still add to the count.

Comment: When I click on 'Going' in my browser on the facebook event side I get to see the full list of people attending, though (names and profile pics). There's got to be a way to get this same list with the API, right?

Comment: disabling the facebook platform means that they don´t show up with the api, but they still show up on facebook.com. there is no way to get their name or any other data if they disabled the platform.

Comment: What about the people having facebook platform enabled and their ID set to private? Not getting these people either, right? So at least for that case there should be a solution

Comment: i would say if they don´t show up then there is no way to get them